# iOS: Download .TXT file give strange result

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I'm trying to download .txt file that has 5MB size in one website

I tried to download file directly and it give the correct size

I tried to download via Android DownloadManager.Request and it also give the correct size

**Except**, in iOS, while I tried to download it via NSURLConnection,
without a 1 second, it show successful download with 5MB size
however, when I check in Network receiving it show I just used only 25kb?

PS. If I change to download the same domain with .zip file, it download properly

problem link: http://www.bluewindsolution.com/speed_test/downloads/download_file.txt

working link:
http://www.bluewindsolution.com/speed_test/downloads/download_file.zip

here is the code

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    let timestamp = NSString(format: "%.0f", NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.bluewindsolution.com/speed_test/downloads/download_file.txt?time=\(timestamp)")!
    var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30.0)
    startDate = NSDate()
    NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
}

func connectionDidFinishDownloading(connection: NSURLConnection, destinationURL: NSURL) {
    println("finishdownload \(destinationURL)")

    println("timetotal: \(timetotal)")
    println("speed: \(speed) mbps")
    println("filesize: \(filesize)") // it's show 5MB but network just receive only 25KBps ?  it's also not the cache because it's happen at the first time also.

    connection.cancel()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, expectedTotalBytes: Int64) {
    let currentDate:NSDate = NSDate()

    let tt = currentDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)
    timetotal = tt // to get total time
    speed = Double(totalBytesWritten)/1024/1024*8/tt  // to get speed MBps
    filesize = Double(totalBytesWritten)/1024/1024  // to get as MB

    // use this to get result as real time
    //println("timetotal: \(totaltime)")
    //println("speed: \() mbps")
    //println("filesize: \()")
}
```

Output result

[image]

Result of Network Receive in Emulator

[image]

Comment: Are you complaining that the file's not all there or that it's not using enough data? NSURLConnection automatically supports gzip. Is the server zipping it up? Also, the OS provides a cache. Is it cached? Is the server returning 304 Not Modified? Wireshark knows all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an interesting answer

my download_file.txt has only character 'x' about 5 million characters to become 5MB

iOS has 'some' algorithm that check the download file has the same character or text (it's also not the cache) and it no need to download the whole 5MB, instead it use network package only 25KB and then generate that repeat character itself ?

from my test, I insert another file name download_file_ios.txt that has mixed characters, and it download with full 5MB

I hope someday this algorithm will be posted

PS. Thanks @Inder Kumar Rathore for pointing me out to check the download file size

[image: Network Usage only 25 KB]

> Network Usage only 25 KB

[image]

> But I get file with 5MB size

Comment: That algorithm might be zip/unzip. I compressed your txt file and it comes of just 7kb

Comment: I use the same file and just change it's type and the result show that,  case 1: .txt .dat .ima .img etc = it download with only 25KB and then generate, case 2: .zip .mp4 and most of type that need to be execute = it download with full 5MB

Comment: I think you should dig into the http how it downloads the data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like problem with the method `connectionDidFinishDownloading`.
Please use the below delegate methods and it's working

```
  var mData = NSMutableData()
  func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    mData.appendData(data)
    println("loading")
  }

  func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString
    let filePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("text.txt")
    mData.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
    println("\(filePath)")
  }

  func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    println("\(error)")
  }
```

Comment: I tried your code and it give the same result with .txt file (I also remove Dowloading delegate)

Comment: Thanks Inder, I found an answer, I post it below

Comment: what exactly is the problem in the OP's code? I don't see any improvement in your code, just doing it differently.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to use the library Alamofire : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

It's a simple HTTP networking library really easy to use.

You can download file juste like this :

```
    let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)

    Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/stream/100", destination: destination)
```